# Parse webrequest to Coinbase gives 401 not authorized

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, coinbase-api

I'm trying to send bitcoin through Coinbase's API, and this is my code:

```
// create object to send as data
var transaction = {
    to : correctusermail, // "my@email.com"
    amount_string : amount, // "1.00"
    amount_currency_iso : currency // "EUR"
};

// get correct auth key from user
var authq = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
authq.get(objectid, {
    success: function(userObject) {
    correctauth = userObject.get("provider_access_token");
    console.log(correctauth);


    console.log(transaction);
    // send post request
    // make post request
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://coinbase.com/api/v1/transactions/send_money',
      headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
      },
      body: {
        access_token: correctauth,
        transaction: transaction

     },
     success: function(httpResponse) {

        response.success(120);


     },
     error: function(httpResponse) {

    console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
                            response.error(111);
      }
    }); 
},
error: function(userObject, error) {

    response.error(150);
}
});
```

As you can see I'm making sure that my `correctauth` var is correct by logging it, which works just fine.

All the other variables are correct, I've checked them. So what am I missing? It's probably very small.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the Coinbase API documentation, the `access_token` should always be part of the URL, e.g.

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://coinbase.com/api/v1/transactions/send_money?access_token=' 
    + correctauth,
  headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
  },
  body: {
    transaction: transaction
  },
  // ... etc ...
```